# I want to get the position of the rectangle when i press a button, from the kv file using the python file, any help would be appreciated

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I tried using ids but it didn't work,

game.py

```
class MainLayout(BoxLayout):

    def rect_position(self):

        px, py = self.ids.rect.pos

        print(px, py)
```

kv file:

```
<MainLayout>:
    orientation: "horizontal"

    Label:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                id: rect
                pos: (self.width/4 + 50, self.height*3/4)
                size: (100, 0)
```

Output:

> position = self.ids.rect.pos File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in
> kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr** AttributeError: 'super'
> object has no attribute '**getattr**'

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `ListProperty` to your `MainWindow` to define the `Rectangle` position. Then the `rect_pos()` method can just return the value of that `ListProperty`:

```
class MainLayout(BoxLayout):
    rect_pos = ListProperty([0, 0])

    def rect_position(self):
        print(self.rect_pos)
```

And in your `kv`, you can use that `ListProperty` as the `Rectangle` position:

```
<MainLayout>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    rect_pos: (self.width/4 + 50, self.height*3/4)

    Label:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: root.rect_pos
                size: (100, 0)
```

This also allows you to adjust the `Rectange` position simply by changing the value of that `ListProperty`.

By the way, you can only assign `ids` to widgets, not graphics instructions.